# Force Windows to use all cores

Tags: windows-8.1, cpu-usage, affinity

I've got Win8.1, and an Intel CPU with 2(4) (logical) Cores.

BUT: Windows only uses 1 core. The Taskmanager shows the 1st CPU permanently at 100%; all others are mostly idle.

After several hours of search I only found out that windows sets the affinity of every process to CPU0. In the taskmanager I could reset the affinity of any process to any other CPU (or to all), but thats not necessarry on my other computer either.

Any other ideas than msconfig (heard that often on the internet, but it does not fix my problem. Windows knows about the other CPUs, they are just not used)?

Comment: are you saying that by default every process has affinity set to core0? the default really should be all cores...

Comment: I can confirm from observation that Windows does not by default set affinity of all processes to Core 0. All cores are used. If this is not happening, something is wrong. Other than the boot options I am not aware of any option that would restrict this.

Comment: @Blaine yes, thats what i mean. i go to Taskmanager and check affinity of any process, only CPU0 is checked.
I also know that this is not ok, this should not be normal, but it somehow is. I want to find out what is wrong and maybe fix without doing a whole reinstall...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it;
Some of the pre-installed Intel-software throttled the CPU. Going to Programms and Features and deleting the Intel thermal plattform fixed and a restart fixed everything.

Answer (score 2):

Please read this link [Psychic debugging](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050321-00/?p=36123)

This Powershell (runas an administrator) script might help discovering which processes have affinity set.

```
get-process | Select Name,ProcessorAffinity
```

This script might at least temporyrily set the mask to all available (1+2+4+8) processors = 15 for a two-core processor with HT (a four-core with hyperthreading = 255)

```
get-process |
  Where{ $_.ProcessorAffinity -eq 1} |
    Foreach{ $_.ProcessorAffinity = 15 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. Reading seems to exatly show my problem (but the links on the page do not work). I tried setting affinity of explorer to all CPUs (via Taskmgr) but windows does not save it (check all boxes -> hit ok -> recheck affinity: Still only CPU0).
I will try powershell later today...

Comment: Sorry for the delay, i tried powershell now. It does not completely work;
select Name,ProcessorAffinity outputs exactly what expected; everything is set to 1.
Running the Script AND the select as one script shows every process set to 15, but if I re-run the select most processes are resetted to 1
Exceptions are some svchost and DptfParticipantProcessorService...
To the link: unfortunately the outgoing links on the site do not work...

Comment: Sorry again, i messed up the line;
The second process staying at 15 is dllhost, not the DptfParticipantProcessorService